# Set with sum pairwise square

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $M$ be a set of positive integers with $n$ elements.
What is the maximum cardinality of the set
$A=\{a+b\text{ is  square}\mid a,b \in M\}$?

Edit: the problem appears in article of research, but can't remember to where

Comment: It looks like some sort of additive combinatorics. But you need to add more details: is $M$ a set of integers? A subset of a ring?

Comment: Subset of positive  integers

Comment: A related question is whether *all* the sums $a+b$ can be squares, if $n$ is large. This is taken up in section D15 of Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. Guy traces that problem back to T Baker in The Gentleman's Diary of 1839. Jean Lagrange in 1970/71 gave a solution for $n=5$. Guy's book was published in 2004,  I don't know what progress has been made since.

Comment: Here is a somewhat more recent publication: https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1666

Comment: @GerryMyerson Since that problem is open, I guess there will be no nontrivial upper bounds forthcoming, but there could be a nontrivial lower bound. We can get $\approx n^{3/2}$ by just taking the numbers from $1$ to $n$ and I don't immediately see how to do any better for large $n$.